# how to speed up query binary search in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I use Linq select statement to get file as byte from the database. It take long time to get the byte array from my Files Table.

I'm using this code:

```
Fun<Files,bool> Filter  = delegate(Files x)
{
     return x.FileID == 10;
}; 
Files File = DAL.FilesDAL.GetFile(Filter).First();


public static List<Files> GetFile(Func<Files,bool> lambda){
return db.Where(lamnda).ToList();
}
```

For 1M file size it take up to 1m. That too long for my clients.

How I can improve the speed of that query?

Comment: The code you shown us is not a query... Show how you use the `Filter` you declared here.

Comment: OK, we got something more. Now, how is `GetFile` defined?

Comment: Any idea  MarcinJuraszek ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the fact, that using `Func<>` makes your query be executed as LINQ to Objects. That means entire table is fetched into application memory and then filtering is performed by the application, not by the database. To make the filter execute at database it should be passed as `Expression<Func<>>` instead:

```
public static List<Files> GetFile(Expression<Func<Files,bool>> lambda){
    return db.Where(lamnda).ToList();
}
```

I assumed, that `db` here is `IQueryable<Files>`.

To call it use:

```
Files File = DAL.FilesDAL.GetFile(x => x.Filter == 10).First();
```

To make it even more descriptive, you should probably change your method to only return one `Files` item. Method name is `GetFile`, so I would expect it to return one file, not collection of files:

```
public static Files GetFile(Expression<Func<Files,bool>> lambda){
    return db.FirstOrDefault(lamnda);
}
```

usage:

```
var File = DAL.FilesDAL.GetFile(x => x.Filter == 10);
```

Or to increase semantics, you can refactor the method to be `GetFileById` and take `Id`, not an expression:

```
public static Files GetFileById(int Id)
{
    return db.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FileId == id);
}
```

usage

```
var File = DAL.FilesDAL.GetFileById(10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot MarcinJuraszek ... It works for me. Now the speed is good.

Answer (score 0):

> How I can improve the speed of that query?

Faster server. Faster network. Do not get the binary content you do not need.

SImple like that. NOthing you can do on LINQ level that will magically fix a bad design.

Generally:

Btw., a bad mistake - you return ToList in GetFiles. Never do that. Either let it a queryable, so the user can add conditions and order and grouping or return an enumerable (which is way less powerfull) but ToList means all gets into memory - even if the user then does not want a list.

And man, the way to hand in the lambdaa is just redundant and limiting. Bad design.

Comment: `ToList()` is not different then returning `IEnumerable<>` - both will materialize the collection somewhere in application memory, sooner or later. But number of items will be the same. And that's not always a bad thing, as long as you fetch and materialize only necessary items, not the entire table.

Comment: `IEnumerable` alone will *not* materialize the query. `MyEnumerable.Any()` will fetch one record, but `MyList.Any()` fetched all records before (to get the list).

Comment: This is the whole idea. Leave it to the use to decide so he can then add things like group by. You should not materialize a query unless needed. Broken design.

Comment: @alzaimar `Any()` on `IEnumerable()` will still bring all data into memory, because `Any` will be executed as LINQ to Objects query, not as EF/LINQ to SQL/anyOtherORMQuery. To make `Any` to be executed on DB you'd have to expose `IQueryable` from your DAL.

Comment: Correct. I mixed that up.